# Why does this function passed as an argument to another function return None?

Tags: python, function

```py
def run_my_func(runner, *args, **kwargs):
    runner(*args)
    
def my_func(name):
    return name
    
out = run_my_func(my_func, "my name is john", kwargs=None)

print(out)
```

Why does this print out `None`?

If I print out the `name` like so:

```py
def run_my_func(runner, *args, **kwargs):
    runner(*args)
    
def my_func(name):
    print(name)
    return name
    
out = run_my_func(my_func, "my name is john", kwargs=None)

print(out)
```

I get the output

```bash
my name is john
None
```

Comment: Its just that *so* many questions have already been asked where the OP is surprised that they see `None`. We don't understand why you haven't found some of them and answered your own question before you got here.

Comment: If you don't explicitly *return* a value from a Python function it will implicitly return None

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function doesn't return the value from the function it calls:

```py
def run_my_func(runner, *args, **kwargs):
    return runner(*args)
    
def my_func(name):
    return name
    
out = run_my_func(my_func, "my name is john", kwargs=None)

print(out)
```

Output as requested.

Also, you can safely use both args and kwargs in calling `runner`, even if it takes no arguments:

```py
def run_my_func(runner, *args, **kwargs):
    return runner(*args, **kwargs)
    
def my_func(name):
    return name
    
out = run_my_func(my_func, "my name is john")

print(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first code, parameter function "my_func" is called. It returns the name parameter that you pass.After that "run_my_func" function is executing the runner function and returns none since you don't use any return statement. So that your variable is None.

In your second code, my_func is first printing the name before returning. The remaining process is the same as the first code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a "return" to runner(*args)

```
def run_my_func(runner, *args, **kwargs):
    return runner(*args)
    
def my_func(name):
    return name
    
out = run_my_func(my_func, "my name is john", kwargs=None)

print(out)  # This will print "my name is john"
```